# No Text to Speech Settings in ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, settings, text-to-speech

I have a Xolo A500 phone running a custom ICS 4.0.4 ROM.  I have installed some TTS apps like Google TTS and SVOX but I am unable to select either of them.  There are no TTS settings inside Settings.

[image: Language and input Menu] [image: Accessibilty Menu]

Please tell me how to access TTS Settings?